# Computing bezier curves of degree n with recursive functions

Tags: c, recursion, computational-geometry

I have been looking at homemade CNC and have been wondering how curves are drawn, so I looked into it and found [this cool article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). I then decided to try coming up with a bezier curve algorithm in C. It seems to work ok, and while I haven't tried plotting points with this exact implementation, it seems to match up with results from a previous implementation that I did plot points with.

```
#include <stdint.h>

static long double bbezier(long double t, long double p0, long double p1){
    return ((p1 - p0) * t) + p0;
}

long double bezier(long double t, uint64_t *points, uint64_t n){
    long double p0 = points[0], p1 = points[1];
    if(n == 1) return bbezier(t, p0, p1);

    long double q0 = bezier(t, points, n - 1),
        q1 = bezier(t, points + 1, n - 1);
    return bbezier(t, q0, q1);
}
```

I then quickly wrote this test program in C++.

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" long double bezier(long double, uint64_t *, uint64_t);

uint64_t pointsx[] = {
    0, 40, 100, 200
};
uint64_t pointsy[] = {
    0, 150, 60, 100
};

int main(){
    for(uint64_t i = 0; i <= 10000; ++i){
        long double ii = i;
        long double j = ii/10000;

        long double x = bezier(j, pointsx, 3);
        long double y = bezier(j, pointsy, 3);

        std::cout << "X: " << x << ", Y: " << y << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote an implementation running in javascript from a lightly modified w3 schools canvas tutorial [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FZ15C1Q1XRZS) to understand how bezier curves work but it only supports 3rd degree curves. It does plot the points though, and that's what I based the above implementation on.

It doesn't make any checks to ensure t is between 0 and 1 and n != 0 but I'm not too worried. The only thing I'm worried about is segfaults in cases where n is so high that you get a stack overflow but that will be a pretty crazy curve. Anyway, how does it look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Recursion**

[Edit]
In `bezier()`, the 2 recursive calls to `bezier()` *is* inefficient as it exponential grows with O(2<sup>n</sup>) and only O(n<sup>2</sup>) operations are needed.   I suspect  better efficiency (linear) can be had  with a pre-computed weighing of the `d[]` terms below.

The concern about seg faulting due to excessive recursion would be mitigated with the above improvement.

I also change function `bbezier()` to code.

```
long double bezier_alt1(long double t, const uint64_t *points, size_t n) {
  assert(n);
  long double omt = 1.0 - t;
  long double d[n];  // Save in between calculations.

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    d[i] = omt * points[i] + t * points[i + 1];
  }
  while (n > 1) {
    n--;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      d[i] = omt * d[i] + t * d[i + 1];
    }
  }
  return d[0];
}
```

[Edit2]

A [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Explicit_definition)  solution O(n) is possible with O(1) additional memory.

```
long double bezier_alt2(long double t, const uint64_t *points, size_t n) {
  assert(n);
  long double omt = 1.0 - t;
  long double power_t = 1.0;
  long double power_omt = powl(omt,n);
  long double omt_div = omt != 0.0 ? 1.0/omt : 0.0;

  long double sum = 0.0;
  unsigned long term_n = 1;
  unsigned long term_d = 1;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    long double y = power_omt*power_t*points[i]*term_n/term_d;
    sum += y;
    power_t *= t;
    power_omt *= omt_div;
    term_n *= (n-i);
    term_d *= (i+1);
  }
  power_omt = 1.0;
  long double y = power_omt*power_t*points[n]*term_n/term_d;
  sum += y;
  return sum;
}
```

Additional linear simplifications possible - perhaps another day.

---

Minor stuff

**Use `const`**

A `const` in the referenced data allows for some optimizations, wider application and better conveys code's intent.

```
// long double bezier(long double t, uint64_t *points, uint64_t n){
long double bezier(long double t, const uint64_t *points, uint64_t n){
```

**Excessive wide type**

With `uint64_t n`, there is no reasonable expectation that such an iteration will finish for large `n`.

Fortunately, `n` indicates the *size* of the array.  For array indexing and sizing, using `size_t`.  It is the right size - not too narrow, nor too wide a type.

```
// long double bezier(long double t, uint64_t *points, uint64_t n){
long double bezier(long double t, uint64_t *points, size_t n){
```

For this application, certainly `unsigned` would always suffice.

**`static`**

Good use of `static` in `static long double bbezier()` to keep that function local.

**Missing `"bezier.h"`**

I'd expect a `bezier()` declaration in a .h file and implementation in the .c file instead of `extern "C" long double bezier(long double, uint64_t *, uint64_t);` in main.c

```
// extern "C" long double bezier(long double, uint64_t *, uint64_t);
#include "bezier.h".
```

**`n` range check**

Perhaps in a debug build, test `n`.

```
long double bezier(long double t, const uint64_t *points, uint64_t n){
  assert( n > 0);    // Low bound
  assert( n < 1000); // Maybe a sane upper limit too
```

Comment: Woah, those loops are smart. But isnt `size_t` the same as `uint64_t` on most machines?

Comment: @user233009 "isn't `size_t` the same as `uint64_t` on most machines?" --> I very much doubt `size_t` is 64-bit on 32-bit or smaller machines.  Most processors in 2019 are small embedded ones (billions per year).  IAC, the assumption is not needed,  serves scant benefit and incurs issues.

Comment: @user233009 I did not know better Bezier algorithms until researching due to this post.  So we both [LSNED](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=LSNED).

Answer (score 4):

- I don't like `bbezier`. It collided too much with `bezier`, and is not very informative. It performs a linear interpolation, so why not call it `interpolate`?
- The `p0` and `p1` just add noise. Consider

  ```
      if (n == 1) {
          return interpolate(t, points[0], points[1]);
      }
  ```

  I would seriously consider getting rid of `q0` and `q1`:

  ```
      return interpolate(t,
                      bezier(t, points, n - 1),
                      bezier(t, points + 1, n - 1));
  ```

  Don't take it as a recommendation.
- The recursion leads to the exponential time complexity. Way before you start having memory problems you'd face a performance problem. Consider computing the Bernstein form instead. It gives you linear time, and no memory problems.

Comment: "It gives you linear time, and no memory problems." Evaluating them in Bernstein form through de Casteljau's algorithm is inefficient: \$n(n+1)/2\$ additions and \$n(n+1)\$ multiplications to calculate a point on a curve of degree \$n\$. Rather, I'd prefer Wang-Ball form. For reference: "[Efficient algorithms for Bézier curves](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0167-8396(99)00048-5)."

Comment: @esote Did I ever mention de Casteljau? A not-so-naive implementation _is_ linear.  Two multiplications and two divisions per term. It will have some _numerical_ issues with large `n`, sure.

Comment: Fair enough, I should've read your answer more carefully.